# Expo 31.0.2: ExpoKit StripeModule is null

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, expo

I ejected from expo for integrating Expo Payments for both IOS and Android. Getting StripeModule as null.

Steps that i have done for Payments

1. expo eject
2. Selected ExpoKit option
3. expo start
4. Ran project on android studio without applying any change of gradle versions
5. As this project’s sdk version was > 30 so there were no changes required for payments integration
6. imports are like this - `import {PaymentsStripe as Stripe} from 'expo-payments-stripe';`
7. initializing Stripe in `componentDidMount` as below:-

   ```
   Stripe.setOptionsAsync({
       publishableKey: 'sk_test_VTUPYk8pxYap0g8fhpg9qdKF',
       androidPayMode: 'test', // Android only
   })
   ```

Getting warning after this code:-

> Exception occurred while executing exported method init on module
>   StripeModule: null

As the StripeModule is null according to the warning above. whenever i call a function to get token, it is giving NullPointerException

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.stripe.android.Stripe.createToken(com.stripe.android.model.Card,
>   java.lang.String, com.stripe.android.TokenCallback)' on a null object
>   reference